# twilio + django calling from browsers

Tags: django, twilio

hello working on django app, I set up twilio voice calls in my app, I realised that users can't call in all browsers, but only brave browser, what might be the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The following [table](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript#supported-browsers) indicates the browsers supported by the Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think we also chatted over email about this.

Twilio Voice officially [supports modern browsers across all operating systems](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript#supported-browsers).

The error you were getting was:

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: twilio.js wasn't able to find WebRTC browser support.
This is most likely because this page is served over http rather than https, which does not support WebRTC in many browsers. Please load this page over https and try again.'
```

Browsers mandate that functions like `getUserMedia`, used to get access to camera and microphone, can only be used on secure origins, that is sites served on `localhost` or over HTTPS. To sort this out, you need to serve your application over HTTPS or in development over `localhost`.